# Queries to mongodb for map type fields

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

My entry is:

```
{
  "_id": 722,
  "mappings": [
    {
      "name": "sercan",
      "test2": {
        "code": "PI"
      },
      "codes": {
        "individual": "false",
        "servicetype": "APPART"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The query is:

```
db.myCollection.find({
                      "mappings.codes":
                                       { "individual" : "false", 
                                         "servicetype" : "APPART" 
                                       } 
                     })
```

That returns the entry. But below query is not:

```
db.myCollection.find({
                      "mappings.codes":
                                       {
                                         "servicetype" : "APPART" ,
                                         "individual" : "false"
                                       } 
                     })
```

As you see only codes order is different.. How can i handle this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your collection, `mappings` is an array. Hence you need to use `$elemMatch`. Try this:

```
db.myCollection.find({"mappings":{$elemMatch:{"test.codes":{"individual":"false","servicetype":"APPART"}}}}).pretty()
```

Comment: can you please examine my question again, one field was wrong, also i tried your solution but not worked :( !